# Are MS-Word files saved to USB also saved on the local hard drive?

Tags: microsoft-word

A friend has called me in a panic: the USB thumb drive with a MS Word file has been misplaced.  Presumably lost on a commercial flight.

The file was created and saved to a USB memory stick.  Are backups or recoverable data saved on the associated laptop's hard disk drive? If so, where?

Comment: One should NEVER work within Word on files on a flash drive. This includes opening, saving, editing, and printing. This is a frequent cause of document corruption and loss of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The file was created and saved to a USB memory stick. Are backups or recoverable data saved on the associated laptop's hard disk drive? If so, where?

Office typically saves files to the document’s chosen location. This also includes any files required to recover the file from an unexpected crash.

However, there is a slim chance that if and only if **Always create backup** was enabled and the user was using Office 365 then one of the following folders will have the Word Backup file (I.e. `filename.wbk`) contained within it.

- `%AppData%\Microsoft\Word`
- `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`

Comment: Thank you: Recovery successful